# Java Binding with Intersystems Cache

Tags: intersystems-cache

I'm new to Cache and I'm trying to use java binding and I have some problems with it.

1) I want to add some entry to the database using code

```
              Database dbconnection = CacheDatabase.getDatabase (url, username, password);

              Patient patient = new Patient(dbconnection);
              patient.setFIO("Antonov Kirill Vladimirovich");

              Diary diary = new Diary(dbconnection);
              diary.setData("Very bad.");
              diary.setDate(new java.sql.Date(2015,11,12));
              diary.setStatus("Unsatisfied");

              ListOfObjects obj = new ListOfObjects(dbconnection);
              obj.add(diary);
              patient.listOfDiariesSetObject(new Oid(obj));

              dbconnection.saveAllObjects();
```

This code causes

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.intersys.classes.ListOfObjects cannot be cast to com.intersys.jdbc.SysList
    at com.intersys.jdbc.SysListProxy.getBinaryData(SysListProxy.java:516)
    at com.intersys.objects.Oid.getData(Oid.java:101)
    at com.intersys.cache.Dataholder.<init>(Dataholder.java:378)
    at smda.Patient.listOfDiariesSetObject(Patient.java:1565)
    at etu.wollen.cache.DBConnector.main(DBConnector.java:34)
```

How should I convert ListOfObjects to Oid correctly?

2) How should I remove some entries from database? I have found only save methods in com.intersys.objects.Database using \Dev\java\samples\doc

3) Most of classes, such as com.intersys.objects.Database, com.intersys.objects.CacheException, ... are deprecated. But official docbook still uses theese classes. Should I use deprecated classes?

```
Patient

    Class smda.Patient Extends %Persistent
{

Property FIO As %String;

Property RegNumber As %String;

Property MedCardNumber As %String;

Property listOfDiaries As list Of Diary;

Property listOfEpisodes As list Of Episode;

Storage Default
{
<Data name="PatientDefaultData">
<Value name="1">
<Value>%%CLASSNAME</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="2">
<Value>FIO</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="3">
<Value>RegNumber</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="4">
<Value>MedCardNumber</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="5">
<Value>listOfDiaries</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="6">
<Value>listOfEpisodes</Value>
</Value>
</Data>
<DataLocation>^smda.PatientD</DataLocation>
<DefaultData>PatientDefaultData</DefaultData>
<IdLocation>^smda.PatientD</IdLocation>
<IndexLocation>^smda.PatientI</IndexLocation>
<StreamLocation>^smda.PatientS</StreamLocation>
<Type>%Library.CacheStorage</Type>
}

Projection PatientJava As %Projection.Java(ROOTDIR = "C:\Projects\Cache\Java");

}

Diary 

    Class smda.Diary Extends %Persistent
{

Property Data As %Text(MAXLEN = 1000);

Property Status As %String;

Property Date As %Date;

Storage Default
{
<Data name="DiaryDefaultData">
<Value name="1">
<Value>%%CLASSNAME</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="2">
<Value>Data</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="3">
<Value>Status</Value>
</Value>
<Value name="4">
<Value>Date</Value>
</Value>
</Data>
<DataLocation>^smda.DiaryD</DataLocation>
<DefaultData>DiaryDefaultData</DefaultData>
<IdLocation>^smda.DiaryD</IdLocation>
<IndexLocation>^smda.DiaryI</IndexLocation>
<StreamLocation>^smda.DiaryS</StreamLocation>
<Type>%Library.CacheStorage</Type>
}

}
```

Comment: you will almost certainly get better answers if you ask distinct questions. I have answered question(1) above, but can't help you on items (2) or (3).

Comment: Can you add how Cache classes looks like?  I mean Patient and Diary.

Comment: Yes. I have added classes to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Just get the value, for this property, it should contain a value with type java.util.List. And then you can manipulate with this list, such as add your value.
instead of

```
          ListOfObjects obj = new ListOfObjects(dbconnection);
          obj.add(diary);
          patient.listOfDiariesSetObject(new Oid(obj));
```

should be

```
        List diaries = patient.getlistOfDiaries();
        diaries.add(diary);
```

2) Every Caché class has own method for create (%New), open (%OpenId) and for delete (%DeleteId) by id objects of this classes. And, projected classes, has their own such static methods. [Here](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=TJAV_ProjectionDetails) in documentation you can see some details about projection classes. So, you can call such code, for delete object with Id=1:

```
Patient.sys_DeleteId(dbconnection, 1);
```

3) Not sure, but I think it is because of Caché eXTreme, which should replace cachedb.jar. You can read more about Java Caché eXTreme [here](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BXJV).

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your first question is in your code. I think you can modify this section:

```
ListOfObjects obj = new ListOfObjects(dbconnection);
obj.add(diary);
patient.listOfDiariesSetObject(new Oid(obj));
```

to be as follows:

```
patient.listOfDiariesSetObject(new Oid(diary));
```

Your initial code is creating a `ListOfObjects` instance that you are then inserting into the `listOfDiaries` property, rather than inserting your `Diary` instance into the list.

Comment: Didn't help for me :( Throwed the same exception: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException` `smda.Diary cannot be cast to com.intersys.jdbc.SysList at` `com.intersys.jdbc.SysListProxy.getBinaryData(SysListProxy.java:516)`. It waits for something compatible with `com.intersys.jdbc.SysList`